# How do I create an error message using pickAFile() in Jython?

Tags: list, file, numbers, message, jython

I am creating a program to do various calculations to a list of numbers.

How can I show an error message if somebody presses "Cancel" while choosing a file with `pickAFile()`? Currently when I cancel it, I get an error message from the `for line in file` line.

The error message is:

```
>"The error was:Stream closed
> I/O operation failed.
> 
> I tried to read a file, and couldn't.  Are you sure that file exists?
> If it does exist, did you specify the correct directory/folder?"
```

Here's my code:

```py
def selectFileCalculateStatistics():

  fullPathName = pickAFile()
  file = open(fullPathName, "r")

  listNumbers = readListNumbers(file)

  min = calculateMinimum(listNumbers)

  max = calculateMaximum(listNumbers)

  mean = calculateMean(listNumbers)

  standardDeviation = calculateStandardDeviation(listNumbers, mean)

  print("The minimum number for this list is: " + str(min))
  print("The maximum number for this list is: \n" + str(max))
  print("The mean number for this list is: " + str(round(mean, 2)))
  print("The standard deviation for this list is: " + str(round(standardDeviation, 2)))

  file.close()


def readListNumbers(fullPathName):

      file = open(fullPathName, "r")
      listNumbers = []

      for line in file:
        listNumbers.append(float(line.rstrip('\n')))

      return listNumbers
```

Comment: In `readListNumbers()`, try to pick a different variable name than `file`. Overriding the built-ins can have strange side-effects.

Comment: Noted, thanks. Any tips on giving an error message though?

Comment: I don’t know Jython, so I’ve never used the `pickAFile()` function. Perhaps look at what it returns if the user selects “Cancel”, and compare to that? e.g. if it returns None, then add a line `if fullPathName is None: [error msg] else: [do some work]`.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the error message, otherwise that would be the way I went about it. 

"The error was:Stream closed
I/O operation failed.
I tried to read a file, and couldn't.  Are you sure that file exists? If it does exist, did you specify the correct directory/folder?"

Comment: Hmm, then I’m out of ideas. But you should add that error message to the question – it will make it easier for somebody else to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `pickAFile()` returns `None` if user pressed cancel button you can raise some exception:

```
fullPathName = pickAFile()
if not fullPathName:
    raise IOError('Cancel pressed')
```